# How sed inserting one blank line not followed by blank line

Tags: sed

How `sed` inserting one blank line on this keep-failing code:

```
sed -Ee '/^---/{n;/^\s*$/b;i \n' -e 'b}; b; q' -- inserting_one.txt

---
n
WORKING_DIR
```

To insert  one blank line right following `---` line not followed by blank line, then keep the rest going on

```
---
WORKING_DIR
```

By using `\\n`: `sed -Ee '/^---/{n;/^\s*$/b;i \\n' -e 'b}; b; q' -- inserting_one.txt` it  inserts  two blank line

```
---


WORKING_DIR
```

Please help guide correct path, thanks much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pattern to match 3 or more hyphens and check that there is at least a single non space on the following line.

```
sed '/^---\+$/{N;s/\n[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]/\n&/}' inserting_one.txt
```

**Explanation**

- `/^---\+$/` Match 3 or more hyphens on the whole line
- `{` Start commands separated by ;

  - `N;` Pull the next line into the pattern space
  - `s/` Start substitution
  - `\n[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]` Match a newline, optional spaces and a non whitespace char to make sure the next line is not empty
  - `/\n&/` Substitute with a newline and the rest of what is matched
- `}` End

Output

```
---

WORKING_DIR
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/^---.*\n.*\S/{P;s/.*\n/\n/};P;D' file
```

Open a two line window.

If the first line begins `---` and the second line is non-empty, print/delete the first line and insert a newline.

Print/delete the first line and repeat.

N.B. The crux of the problem is to realise that the non-blank line following a line beginning `---` may be a line beginning `---`.